# Monitor the number of processes spawned by subprocess in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, process

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
import subprocess
nproc = 0
for i in range(100):
    subprocess.Popen(commands[i], when_finished="nproc -= 1")
    nproc += 1

while nproc > 0:
    print("%d processes running..." % nproc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poll the processes:

```
import subprocess
processes = [subprocess.Popen(command) for command in commands]
while True:
    nproc = sum(p.poll() is None for p in processes)
    if not nproc:
        break
    print("%d processes running..." % nproc)
    sleep(0.1)
```